# Expandable box CSS margin-top

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a CSS based expandable box with arbitrary content. My approach is this:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.expandContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expandContents {
  margin-top: -100%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~label~.expandContainer .expandContents {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="expandme" />
<label for="expandme">Expand this content</label>

<div class="expandContainer">
  <div class="expandContents">
    <p>Expanded Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the label is clicked, the hidden input is checked and the style of `.expandContents` goes from `margin-top: -100%` to `margin-top: 0`.

I can't use `display: none` because I'd like to have the action be animated a little bit with a `transition` property, which I didn't include in the example for simplicity.

The problem I discovered is that `margin-top` is based on the width of the element, rather than the height, so if the contents are too tall or the container too narrow, then the bottom of the contents are visible when collapsed.

Is there a way to approach this or is this impossible without using a JavaScript calculation somewhere?

Comment: ...why not just use `<details><summary>`?

Comment: This is a useful reference, I wasn't aware of these. However, it does seem like there are some limitations to styling this, at the very least that you can't animate the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-height` is often used to achieve this in a way that can be animated.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.expandContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expandContents {
  max-height: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~label~.expandContainer .expandContents {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="expandme" />
<label for="expandme">Expand this content</label>

<div class="expandContainer">
  <div class="expandContents">
    <p>Expanded Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach worked much better, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the aproach, instead of margin try playing with a `position: relative;` parent(your `.expandContainer`)  and a `position:absolute;` on your `.expandContents` then use `left: -100%;` and `left: 0;` respectively on your css, and then you can add an animation to that transition. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow. Only changing position will mean that the contents are visible (just positioned somewhere else) when the box is not expanded. Is the idea that this would result in the contents being positioned out of the viewport?

Comment: Is not just the positions, the parent having the position relative and the child having the absolute property is what makes it able to get out of the viewport and behave as you want, note that content below this will get behind the expanded content though

Comment: You should expand on this with an interactive Stack Snippet. The `<>` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `opacity:0` for the content instead of `display:none`. In that way, you could use a `@keyframe` animation that takes care both of making the content visible and translated. Try adding this tp your code. You may need to fix some timing, but it should make the trick

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.expandContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expandContents {
  margin-top: -100%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~label~.expandContainer .expandContents {
  animation: slideDown .3s forwards
}



@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  10% {
    opacity:1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="expandme" />
<label for="expandme">Expand this content</label>

<div class="expandContainer">
  <div class="expandContents">
    <p>Expanded Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a good idea, though it doesn't necessarily provide a smooth animation since the movement "starts" at some point not at the bottom of the content box, if that makes sense. That said, it's probably good enough for most cases.